# Row sum of $P^{m}$ when row sum of $P$ is $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let  $P$  be  an  $n\times n$  matrix  whose  row  sum  equals  $1$. Then  for  any  positive  integer  $m$  , what   is  the  row  sum  of  $P^{m}$ ?

Now  I  took  arbitrary  $2\times 2$  matrix ,say, $A$  and multiplied  it  with  itself  for  $3$  times  and  the  row  sum  of  $A^{3}$  is  also  $1$.  So  can  I  assume  the  row  sum  of  $P^{m}$  will  also  be $1$ $?$  But  this  is just  intuition.  How  to  prove ?  Some  lead  please.

Thanks.

Comment: $(1,1,1,\cdots,1)^{t}$ ($n$-$1$'s) is an eigenvector of $P$ with eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: To me the row sum of a $n\times n$ matrix is $n$-tuple of numbers, not one number. Even then it would be good to be clear whether you mean the "sum of the rows" (a row obtained by summing each column) or the "vector of rows sums" (which is the sum of the columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $P^k$ has all row sums $1$ for some $k \geq 1$. Then the $i$-th row sum of $P^{k+1} = P^k \cdot P$ is

$$\sum_{j = 1}^n \sum_{m=1}^n (P^k)_{im} P_{mj} = \sum_{m=1}^n (P^k)_{im} \sum_{j=1}^n P_{mj} = 1 \cdot 1 = 1$$

By induction $P^k$ has all row sums $1$ for all $k \geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Row sum is multiplication from the right with the column vector $\bf 1$ consisting of ones. That row sum is 1 basically means that $\bf A1 = 1$, i.e. that the vector $\bf 1$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$. By multiplying with $\bf A$ to the left you will see that ${\bf A}^2 \bf1 = A1$, and you see that by systematically multiplying with $\bf A$ to the left you will be able to do the induction above which SRX showed, i.e. that ${\bf A}^{k+1} {\bf1 = A}^{k}\bf 1$.